# Need help for string manipulation in a bash script

Tags: bash, substring, string-length

I'm not use to the syntax of bash script. I'm trying to read a file. For each line I want to keep only the part of the string before the delimiter '/' and put it back into a new file if the word respect a perticular length. I've download a dictionary, but the format does not meet my expectation. Since there is 84000 words, I don't really want to manualy remove what after the '/' for each word. I though it would be an easy thing and I follow couple of idea in other similar question on this site, but it seem that I'm missing something somewhere because it still doesn't work. I can't get the length right. The file Test_Input contains one word per line. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
filename="Test_Input.txt"
while read -r line
do
    sub= echo $line | cut -d '/' -f1
    length= echo ${#sub}
    if $length >= 4 && $length <= 10;
        then echo $sub >> Test_Output.txt
    fi
done < "$filename"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several items:

1. I assume that you have been using single back-quotes in the assignments, and not literally `sub= echo $line | cut -d '/' -f1`, as this would have certainly failed. Alternatively, you can also use `sub=$()`, as in `$(echo $line | cut -d '/' -f1)`
2. The conditions in an `if` clause need to be encompassed by single or double `[]`, like this: `if [[ $length -ge 4 ]] && [[ $length -le 10 ]];`
3. Which brings me to the next point: `<=` doesn't reliably work in bash. Just use `-ge` for "greater or equal" and `-le` for "less or equal".
4. If your line does not contain any `/` characters, in your version `sub` will contain the whole line. This might not be what you want, so I'd advise to also add the `-s` flag to `cut`.
5. You don't need `somevar=$(echo $someothervar)`. Just use `somevar=$someothervar`

Here's a version that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
filename="Test_Input.txt"
while read -r line
do
    sub=$(echo $line | cut -s -d '/' -f 1)
    length=${#sub}
    if [[ $length -ge 4 ]] && [[ $length -le 10 ]];
        then echo $sub >> Test_Output.txt
    fi
done < "$filename"
```

Of course, you could also just use `sed`:

```
sed -n -r '/^[^/]{4,10}\// s;/.*$;;p' Test_Input.txt > Test_Output.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-n` Don't print anything unless explicitly marked for printing.
- `-r` Use the extended regex
- `/<searchterm>/ <operation>` Search for lines that match a certain criteria, and perform this operation:

  - Searchterm is: `^[^/]{4,10}\/` From the beginning of the line, there should be between 4 and 10 non-slash characters, followed by the slash
  - Operation is: `s;/.*$;;p` replace everything between the first slash and the end of the line with nothing, then print.

Comment: Just a little precision, the double `[[` didn't work at all, I use the single one. Thank you very much! I knew it I wasn't very far! :)

Comment: Finally the `[[` work fine! Seem that Ioading our script with `sh ./script.sh` rather than `bash ./script.sh` has less compatibility something like that.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is the best tool for this

`awk -F/ 'length($1) >= 4 && length($1) <= 10 {print $1} > newfile`